# MySQL Stored Procedure that Calls a Table w/ dynamic Name

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, prepare

I have a stored procedure in `MySQL` that calls a function that inserts values into a table. 
The insert statement is like

```
INSERT INTO Table1 SELECT * from Table2
```

`Table2` has a variable name, depending on the date the procedure is called, like 
`table_201410` , if the procedure was called in October 2014. Soevery month, the procedure should make the select from another table.

I have read some answers about preparing and executing, however as I am new to `MySQL/Programming`. I am a bit lost.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a prepared statement like this:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE copy_table $$
CREATE PROCEDURE copy_table ()
BEGIN

    set @table_name = date_format(now(),'%Y%m'); -- getting year and month

    -- concatenating
    set @sql =  concat('INSERT INTO Table1 SELECT * from table_',@table_name);


    -- creating a prepared statement and executing
    PREPARE insert_stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE insert_stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE insert_stmt;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```